# How are Sentry's public key protected when the token is in front end code?

Tags: authentication, api, token

In Sentry's [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/) they explain that you can use a public token to use their API;

```
<script
  src="https://js.sentry-cdn.com/examplePublicKey.min.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

How is examplePublicKey from being used by an attacker and using my account ? Is it a secure way of doing things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public key, as the name suggests, is public. It can be used to report front-end errors, and there is not really a reliable way to prevent someone from abusing that.

There is an [issue discussing security implications of making the public key public](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/15877) where a Sentry maintainer explained:

> If you have just a Sentry DSN, you can't access or modify any data at all. You can only submit new crashreports.